# Writing XML formatted text to output file in Python

Tags: python, xml

I am having issues while writing the below XML to output file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="CoreNLP-to-HTML.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<root>
 <document>
  <sentences>
   <sentence id="1">
    <tokens>
     <token id="1">
      <word>
       Pusheen
      </word>
      <CharacterOffsetBegin>
       0
      </CharacterOffsetBegin>
      <CharacterOffsetEnd>
       7
      </CharacterOffsetEnd>
      <POS>
       NNP
      </POS>
     </token>
    </tokens>
   </sentence>
  </sentences>
 </document>
</root>
```

How to write this to output file in `xml` format? I tried using below write statement

```
tree.write(open('person.xml', 'w'), encoding='unicode').
```

But, I am getting the below error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I don't have to build XML here as I already have the data in XML format. I just need it to write it to a XML file.

Comment: If you *were* to go this route, you would want `open('person.xml', 'w').write(tree)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `tree` is your XML, it is a string. You probably want something like:

```
with open("person.xml", "w", encoding="unicode") as outfile:
  outfile.write(tree)
```

(It is good practice to use `with` for files; it automatically closes them after)

The error is caused by the fact that, since `tree` is a string, you can't write to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs. It worked although with little modification.   with open("output.xml", "w") as outfile:
  outfile.write(pretty_bs)

Comment: You probably want `encoding="utf-8"`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `lxml` module to check the format first and then write it to a file.  I notice that you've got two elements with the same *id*, which caught my eye. It doesn't flag an error in XML, but it could cause trouble on an HTML page, where each *id* is supposed to be unique. 
Here's the simple code to do what I described above:

```
from lxml import etree
try:
    root = etree.fromstring(your_xml_data) # checks XML formatting, returns Element if good
    if root is not None:
        tree = etree.ElementTree(root)  # convert the Element to ElementTree
        tree.write('person.xml')        # we needed the ElementTree for writing the file
except:
    'Oops!'
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Will use the lxml to check format.